# VBscript checking for events in lifetime of script

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbScript which I use to stop, start and restart services.  It works but I have one little niggle.  I hoped to be able to watch for the Service State change events (7036) in the Event log by

```
StartTime=CDate(Now())

.... service stop/start commands etc

Set colServiceEvents = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
       ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent " _
           & "Where Logfile = 'System'" _
           & " and EventCode = '7036'" _
        & " and TimeWritten >'" & StartTime & "'" )
```

By fiddling the StartTime I can see 7036 Events in the last few minutes but I can't seem to see service state change events within the life of the script.  Am I missing something or this a windows "feature"?
 To be clear the script works and I can verify the status by query on Win32_Service but I'd like to know for future reference. 
"There's more than 1 way to skin a cat in vbscript but most of them seem to involve a chain gun and a mincer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is related to the date-time values​​.
Look at the article (especially part `Converting VBScript dates to WMI Dates`) from : http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Working-with-Dates-in-WMI/

Comment: Thanks, explains a lot.  I shall now beat my head against my desk then RTFM.